# AWS EC2 Volume Larger SSD or smaller volume with Provisioned IOPS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Just creating a couple new small volumes for a new SQL server's TempDB files. So I only need 2 20GB volumes but noiticed on pricing that:

- General Purpose (SSD) - 500GB - 1500 / 3000IOPS = **$51.70**
- Provisioned
  IOPS (SSD) - 20GB - 1500 IOPS = **$110.76**

But something is telling me deep down that Provisioned IOPS must surely offer something more such as a guarentee yet general purpose gives you IOPS in the range of 1500 but based on how much strain the rest of the volumes are under? Else what's the point in using the smaller volume with provisioned IOPS?

Regards
Liam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some applications, "predictable performance" is more important than "high performance", and PIOPS gives you both. One should always test, but for the case case you described, GP2 SSD really seems more efficient.

You can get even more out of GP2 combining volumes using RAID/LVM. For example, 1 1TB => 3K IOPS max, 2 x 500 GB => 6K IOPS max...

Comment: Hi Julio, Thanks for the answer, I just needed some reassurance that the GP2 SSD  would be fine, in the past I've always just created PIOPS as I've not been sure and our older system has over 2,500 databases, the new one is 1 db for all 2,500 customers so much easier to change things around (just larger data).